# Декомпиляция модулей на Java

Tags: java, декомпиляция

Пытаюсь декомпилировать модуль веб-сервиса EAR -> WAR -> JAR -> CLASS -> JAVA.

Использую **fernflover** с параметрами по умолчанию.

Часто кода что получаю на выходе:

```
var10001 = "ctlg_guid";
     String var10002 = catalog.getGuid();

     try {
        var8 = var8.setParameter(var10001, var10002);
     } catch (RuntimeException var6) {
        JpaExceptionTranslatorAspect.aspectOf().ajc$afterThrowing$org_springframework_orm_jpa_aspectj_JpaExceptionTranslatorAspect$1$18a1ac9(var6);
        throw var6;
     }
```

1. Можно ли сказать что код обфусцирован, или я ЧДНТ?
2. Есть ли более эффективные инструменты декомпиляции\деобфускации?
3. Где можно почитать про декомпиляцию ярников?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Нет. Этот код не обфусцирован. Просто он изначально написан не на Java, а на [AspectJ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AspectJ) - это отдельный язык программирования и компилятор, генерирующий байт-код совместимый с виртуальной машиной Java.
   Корректно декомпилировать его `fernflover` пока не умеет - поэтому и получается такие нечитаемые конструкции.
2. `fernflover` по праву считается одним из лучших декомпиляторов.
3. В [соседнем проекте "Stack Exchange 
   Reverse Engineering"](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/java), например :) Ну и хоть это и не принято здесь, но поищете в гугле по фразе "java reverse engineering" - различных сайтов, блогов, статей - очень-очень много, и порекомендовать что-то одно подходящее всем практически невозможно.

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ, теперь все ясно :)

Answer (score 2):

Jar-файл - это по сути обычный архив, который можно распаковать с помощью, например, WinRar. Для декомпиляции байт-кода в исходный код есть множество разных средств, которые легко можно найти через поисковик. Например, [Java Decompiler](http://jd.benow.ca/) с GUI-интерфейсом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В Intellij Idea, начиная с 14 версии, есть [встроенный декомпилятор](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2014/07/intellij-idea-14-eap-138-1029-is-out/).

По поводу приведенного фрагмента кода, то он очень похож на обфусцированный код. Можете попробовать [JDO](https://github.com/fileoffset/JDO) для деобфускации.

Comment: Встроенный в Intellij Idea декомпилятор - это собственно и есть обсуждаемый `fernflover` ;)

Comment: Спасибо, не знал

Answer (score 2):

`fernflower` достаточно приличный декомпилятор(с недавних пор является частью IntelliJ), но если мне не изменяет память, то деобфускация идет в виде отдельных модулей.

Вы можете попробовать воспользоваться [онлайн-сервисом](http://www.javadecompilers.com/) который предоставляет возможность воспользоваться различными актуальными декомпиляторами. Если сервис не поможет, то вам придется ручками править части кода.

Comment: Спасибо за подсказки!